# Testing Eclipse UI performance

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to measure the UI performance of Eclipse 4.3 against 4.2.2. There are not a lot of resources on this subject anywhere. I work on Android, so I basically want to measure how much time it takes to clean, build and run an application on both versions.

I have been using Eclipse since quite some time but am a noob when it comes to the Eclipse framework so any pointers will be appreciated :)

Comment: It does not sound like your test is so UI intensive?? The Eclipse build does include a number of performance tests for the UI itself.

Comment: Yeah, I tried running them with no luck. Is there a resource that shows you how to do that which I am not able to find?

Comment: I don't have an references to any such resources. Sorry. You might find something on the Eclipse Wiki or be able to dig via the Eclipse download site.